# Adding Twitter Jar File as a Maven dependency in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, twitter, maven-dependency

How can I add the Twitter4j core jar file as a Maven dependency in my project please? I am using eclipse Java.

Comment: It's the first hit if you search it here: https://mvnrepository.com/

Answer (score 1):

Add the following *dependency* in the pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
     <version>4.0.7</version>
 </dependency>
```